# how do I identify rows where an element appears for the first time?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame of student records. what I want is to identify students who joined a certain program in 2014 for the first time when they were in 9th grade.

```
names.first<-c('a','a','b','b','c','d')
names.last<-c('c','c','z','z','f','h')
year<-c(2014,2013,2014,2015,2015,2014)
grade<-c(9,8,9,10,10,10)

df<-data.frame(names.first,names.last,year,grade)
df
```

To do this, I have used the following statement to say that I want students where the program `year==2014` and their `grade ==9.`

```
 df$first.cohort<-ifelse(df$year==2014 & df$grade==9,1,0)
df



  names.first names.last year grade first.cohort
1           a          c 2014     9            1
2           a          c 2013     8            0
3           b          z 2014     9            1
4           b          z 2015    10            0
5           c          f 2015    10            0
6           d          h 2014    10            0
```

However, as you can notice this would include students who didn't enter the program in year 2014 such as student `a`who started in 2013. How do I create a ifelse statement where I only capture students who are in 9th grade and started the program in 2014 for the first time so that the `df` looks like

```
  names.first names.last year grade first.cohort
1           a          c 2014     9            0
2           a          c 2013     8            0
3           b          z 2014     9            1
4           b          z 2015    10            0
5           c          f 2015    10            0
6           d          h 2014    10            0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `first` after `arrange`ing by 'name' and 'year' to create the logical expression

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   arrange(names, year) %>% 
   group_by(names) %>% 
   mutate(first.cohort = as.integer(grade == 9 & first(year) == 2014))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   names [4]
#  names  year grade first.cohort
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>        <int>
#1 a      2013     8            0
#2 a      2014     9            0
#3 b      2014     9            1
#4 b      2015    10            0
#5 c      2015    10            0
#6 d      2014    10            0
```

For keeping the same order as in the input dataset, we can create a sequence column first and then do the `arrange` on the column after the `mutate`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   arrange(names, year) %>% 
   group_by(names) %>% 
   mutate(first.cohort = as.integer(grade == 9 & first(year) == 2014)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   arrange(rn) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

---

Or using the same logic with `data.table` that have the additional advantage of keeping the same order as in the input dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(names, year), first.cohort := as.integer(grade == 9 &
           first(year) == 2014), names]
```

#### Update

With the new example in the OP's post, we do the grouping by both the 'names' column

```
df %>% 
   arrange(names.first, names.last, year) %>%
   group_by(names.first, names.last) %>%
   mutate(first.cohort = as.integer(grade == 9 & first(year) == 2014))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   names.first, names.last [4]
#  names.first names.last  year grade first.cohort
#  <fct>       <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>        <int>
#1 a           c           2013     8            0
#2 a           c           2014     9            0
#3 b           z           2014     9            1
#4 b           z           2015    10            0
#5 c           f           2015    10            0
#6 d           h           2014    10            0
```

Comment: For data.table, rowid like `with(df, rowid(names) == 1 & year == 2014 & grade == 9)`

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the message.  Are you getting two TRUE with that approach  `setDT(df)[, (rowid(names) == 1) & (year == 2014) & (grade == 9)]#
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: @akrun my actual data set has first and last names and I updated the example to reflect that. how can I do the ordering when I have both first and last names?

Comment: @Nathan123  Updated the answer

Comment: @akrun Oh, I see, OP's data is not sorted for some reason, so ... `df[order(year), v := rowid(names.first, names.last) == 1 & year == 2014 & grade == 9]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(names)%>%dplyr::mutate(Fc=as.numeric((year==2014&grade==9)&(min(year)==2014)))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   names [4]
   names  year grade    Fc
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      a  2014     9     0
2      a  2013     8     0
3      b  2014     9     1
4      b  2015    10     0
5      c  2015    10     0
6      d  2014    10     0
```