# how to insert a logical value based on a whether it has a previous value?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.frame` of students that joined a specific program

```
library(data.table)

f.name<-c('a','a','b','b','b','c','c')
year<-c(2014,2015,2013,2014,2015,2015,2016)
grade<-c(9,10,8,9,10,7,8)

f.name<-as.character(f.name)

df.have<-data.frame(f.name,year,grade)
df.have
```

I'm specifically interested in 9th graders that joined a specific program in 2014. However, I want to distinguish between 9th graders who joined this program in 2014 for the first time, and 9th graders who are returning to the program (who were 8th graders in 2013)

I was able to create a column to distinguish 9th graders who joined this program for the first time in 2014 in the following manner

```
df.have$new.students<-with(df.have, rowid(f.name) == 1 & year == 2014 & grade == 9)
df.have
  f.name year grade new.students
1      a 2014     9         TRUE
2      a 2015    10        FALSE
3      b 2013     8        FALSE
4      b 2014     9        FALSE
5      b 2015    10        FALSE
6      c 2015     7        FALSE
7      c 2016     8        FALSE
```

How can I create another column to tag returning students. Those who were in 8th grade in 2013 and are returning in 2014? so that it looks like this

```
  f.name year grade new.student returning.students
1      a 2014     9        TRUE    FALSE
2      a 2015    10       FALSE    FALSE
3      b 2013     8       FALSE    FALSE
4      b 2014     9       FALSE    TRUE
5      b 2015    10       FALSE    FALSE
6      c 2015     7       FALSE    FALSE
7      c 2016     8       FALSE    FALSE
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501620/how-do-i-identify-rows-where-an-element-appears-for-the-first-time/52501779#52501779, change the min(Year)<2014

Comment: If you know that your data has no gaps and no skipping or repeating of grades, rowid == 2 works (since it would imply that the first row is 2013 grade 8). Or just check rowid != 1 if this is meant to be complementary to the other column. Otherwise, it's a bit messier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a join to look up the desired rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.have)

# initialize to FALSE
df.have[, rs := FALSE]

# update to TRUE if the desired row is found
df.have[year == 2014 & grade == 9, rs := 
  df.have[replace(copy(.SD), c("year", "grade"), list(2013, 8)), on=.(f.name, year, grade), .N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0L
]
```

This could be done with `by=` and `any` or `cumsum`, but I guess it's less efficient:

```
df.have[, v := 
  year == 2014 & grade == 9 & any(year == 2013 & grade == 8)
, by=f.name]

# or...
df.have[order(year), v := 
  year == 2014 & grade == 9 & cumsum(year == 2013 & grade == 8)
, by=f.name]
```

Comment: when i run this it says `Error in 1[.data.frame(df.have, , `:=`(v, year == 2014 & grade == 9 &  : 
  unused argument (by = f.name)`

Comment: @Nathan123 I've added a line with setDT. If you run that first, I think it might handle that error

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use `dplyr`, you can do this with a `group_by` and take advantage of the `row_number()` function.

```
library(dplyr)
df.have %>% 
  group_by(f.name) %>% 
  mutate(new_student = (grade == 9 & year == 2014 & row_number() == 1), 
         returning_student = (grade == 9 & year == 2014 & row_number() > 1)) %>%
  ungroup()

  f.name  year grade new_student returning_student
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>       <lgl>            
1 a       2014     9 TRUE        FALSE            
2 a       2015    10 FALSE       FALSE            
3 b       2013     8 FALSE       FALSE            
4 b       2014     9 FALSE       TRUE             
5 b       2015    10 FALSE       FALSE            
6 c       2015     7 FALSE       FALSE            
7 c       2016     8 FALSE       FALSE
```

Unfortunately, I'm not well versed in `data.table`, so I can't provide an answer specific to that package.

Comment: I believe a data table equivalent would be `df.have[, c("new_student", "returning_student") := list(grade == 9 & year == 2014 & .I == 1, grade == 9 & year == 2014 & .I > 1), by = f.name)]` (untested).